# Best-Practice in word-embeddings

Tags: llm, embeddings

In my project I follow the retrieval augmented generation (RAG) approach. I want to create embeddings for my own dataset and use it in combination with llama-2. In the dataset are german annual reports, 548 reports as pdf-files with about 300 sites per report. Next, I want to load the data in a vector store, but first I think I have to create the embeddings.

And now, there are serveral questions and I need some best-practice:

1. Do I have to train my own embeddings model or can I use models like word2vec of the gensim package or a pretrained model like BERT and take the hidden state?
2. Can I use any embeddings model? I think they train on a specific corpus and if my words aren't in the training corpus, I will get bad result or what do you think?

I hope you can grap me under the arms and help me to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to train my own embeddings model or can I use models like word2vec of the gensim package or a pretrained model like BERT and take the hidden state?

One can use pretrained models. [sentence-transformers](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers) has more recent models.

> Can I use any embeddings model?

The pretrained model needs to support the language of your document, e.g.
https://www.sbert.net/docs/pretrained_models.html?highlight=german

> if my words aren't in the training corpus, I will get bad result or what do you think?

If out-of-vocabulary words are an issue, one can finetune the pretrained models.

Comment: there is the post --> https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/397/embeddings-how-can-i-find-out-that-im-out-of-vocabulary
Let me know, if I have to be concreter in my questioning.

Comment: Why do you mention sentence transformers? Isn't the question about general text transformers?